# Does display: inline change the allowance to wrap a div in a p element

Tags: html, css

I am wondering whether this will work`<p>some text<div> </div></p>`
And `div{
Display: inline;
}`

Comment: I think the answer is simple : "try an see if it works"

Comment: Test it yourself this is not a website where you can let other people test your stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this won't work - as seen in [this answer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjup8-pnIneAhUUO3AKHS7OBdQQFjAMegQIChAS&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8397852%2Fwhy-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it&usg=AOvVaw1DdyULmWDyTPDk5QVKZoLh), because:

> The opening `<div>` tag will **automatically** close the `<p>` tag.